# Finding entries with duplicate values in an array inside a JSON Object returned from an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, chakram

I have an API which has a response like this

```
{conditions:{,…}
individuals:[{employee_id: 12300, employee_type: "Permanent", person_id: "1211211", full_name: "John Jacobs",…},…]
page_num:5
rows:10
total_count:213}
```

Each entry inside the `individuals` array looks like this

```
[ { employee_id: 12300,
    employee_type: 'Permanent',
    person_id: '1211211',
    full_name: 'John Jacobs',
    email_id: 'john_jacobs@gmail.com',
    person_role: [ 
    {rg_code: "AP",
    cl_code: "12",
    data : "South East Asia",
    loc_code : "IN"},

    {rg_code: "CD",
    cl_code: "15",
    data : "Middle East Asia",
    loc_code : "QY"},

    {rg_code: "AP",
    cl_code: "12",
    data : "South East Asia",
    loc_code : "IN"},

    {rg_code: "DF",
    cl_code: "34",
    data : "South East Europe",
    loc_code : "FR"}
     ],
    staffings: [ {id: 1244,
    ind_id: 113322,
    p_id : 112,
    p_name: "Bollywood"},

     {id: 1245,
    ind_id: 112322,
    p_id : 113,
    p_name: "Tollywood"},
    ],
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Jacobs',
    location:
     { country: 'India',
       region: 'South Asia',
       code: 'SA/IN',
       name: 'Bangalore' },
    assistants: [ {} ],
    job_title: 'SSE-2',
    person_full_name: 'John Jacobs'}
     ]
```

I'm trying to find all entries inside the `individuals` array that have duplicate entries of same `loc_code` inside `person_role` - for eg - in the example entry given below there are two entries for `loc_code = 'IN'`. Is the solution possible without use of `for loops` and only with the use of `filter` and `reduce` methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filter and then reduce to construct a Set of the loc_codes for that person. If the set has the same number of values than the original number of persons, that means they are all different. The performance can be improved, as it walks the whole person_role array even when it could stop at the first duplicate.

```
var filtered = individuals.filter(el => {
    return el.person_role.reduce( (prev, cur) => { 
        return prev.add(cur.loc_code);
    }, new Set() ).size !== el.person_role.length;
});


console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working. I'll create a gist with more details.It throws error at the `reduce` method saying it cannot read property reduce of undefined.

Comment: I tried with your example in https://jsfiddle.net/6tu810s5/ Perhaps some of the individuals don't have the person_role key set?

Comment: Here is the link to the gist https://gist.github.com/zac11/13a7478bf08b4b05792e55e31dac9a9c

Comment: I tried with the gist here and it worked https://jsfiddle.net/6tu810s5/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the size of unique items with the total size. My solution involves doing it with `reduce` and extracting a filtering functionality into a separate function:

```
function hasDuplicateLoc({ person_role }) {

    const uniq = person_role.reduce((all, {loc_code}) => {

        if (!all.includes(loc_code)) all.push(loc_code);
        return all;

    }, []);

    return person_role.length !== uniq.length;

}

const result = individuals.filter(hasDuplicateLoc);

console.log(result);
```